# Manter um menu dropdown sempre aberto

Tags: javascript, jquery

Utilizando plugin **Jquery DropDown**: https://github.com/soundasleep/jquery-dropdown
Para criar vários estilos de menu, ele é simples e fácil de se customizar. Queria ver se seria possível manter ele sempre aberto, — depois de ter clicado para abrir.Não fechando quando clicado no body, seja com o clique direito/esquerdo, mas fechar apenas quando clicado no botão dele novamente, que estará intitulado **Fechar**.

```js
$("#jq-dropdown-1").on("click",function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#jq-dropdown-1').dropdown('show');
});
```

```css
.fechar {
  display:none;
}
.jq-dropdown-open .abrir {
  display:none
}
.jq-dropdown-open .fechar {
  display:block
}
```

```html
<link href="https://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/jquery.dropdown.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/jquery.dropdown.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" data-jq-dropdown="#jq-dropdown-1"><span class="abrir">Abrir Dropdown</span><span class="fechar">Fechar</span></a>
<div id="jq-dropdown-1" class="jq-dropdown jq-dropdown-tip">
    <ul class="jq-dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Science</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Eletronics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pellentesque convallis enim.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Internet</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Source:** http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/

Comment: Cara na moral abandona esse plugin, ele é muito ruim, a documentação é rídicula e não vejo necessidade nenhuma neste plugin, pois ele retorna um dropdown normal, igual ao do Html. Repito, não vejo a menor necessidade dele.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você nem precisa do `.js` desse plugin. Pode apenas usar o CSS dele e o script abaixo, veja:

```js
$("[data-jq-dropdown], .jq-dropdown-menu").on("click", function(e){
   
   e.stopPropagation();

   if($(this).is("[data-jq-dropdown]")){
      var menuid = $(this).data("jq-dropdown");

      $("[data-jq-dropdown]")
      .not($(this))
      .removeClass("jq-dropdown-open");

      $(this)
      .toggleClass("jq-dropdown-open");

      $(".jq-dropdown")
      .not($(menuid))
      .hide();
   
      $(menuid)
      .toggle();
   }else{
      $(".jq-dropdown").hide();

      $("[data-jq-dropdown]")
      .removeClass("jq-dropdown-open");
   }
});

$(document).on("keyup mousedown", function(e){
   if(e.keyCode === 27) $('.jq-dropdown-open').trigger('click');
   if(e.type == "mousedown") $("[fechafora].jq-dropdown-open", this).trigger('click');
});

$("[fechafora], .jq-dropdown").on("mousedown", function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.fechar {
  display:none;
}
.jq-dropdown-open .abrir {
  display:none
}
.jq-dropdown-open .fechar {
  display:block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/jquery.dropdown.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="#" data-jq-dropdown="#jq-dropdown-1">
   <span class="abrir">Abrir Dropdown1</span><span class="fechar">Fechar</span>
</a>
<div id="jq-dropdown-1" class="jq-dropdown jq-dropdown-tip">
    <ul class="jq-dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Science1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Eletronics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pellentesque convallis enim.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Internet</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br>
<a href="#" data-jq-dropdown="#jq-dropdown-2" fechafora>
   <span class="abrir">Abrir Dropdown2</span><span class="fechar">Fechar</span>
</a>
<div id="jq-dropdown-2" class="jq-dropdown jq-dropdown-tip">
    <ul class="jq-dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Science2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Eletronics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pellentesque convallis enim.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Internet</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Como sempre, brilhante. É exatamente isso. Só uma coisa que eu esqueci de colocar na pergunta.  Ele pode poderia também fechar quando clicado nos links dentro dele, mas apenas com o click normal.

Comment: Pretendo usar seu código. Percebi que é melhor mesmo que o plugin. Agora também poderia ter classes de controle, para o botão e o conteúdo. `js-button-active` e `js-content-active`

Comment: Simplesmente Perfeito. Thx.

Comment: no dropdown que eu estava usando, eu tinha conseguido colocar para que o dropdown fechasse com a tecla ESC. Usei esse código:
`$(document).keyup(function(e) {
     if (e.keyCode === 27) $('.jq-dropdown').jqDropdown('hide');
});
`
Seria possível adiciona-lo na sua solução?

Comment: Incrível. Devo dizer que estou impressionado com essa solução. Falo da do dropdown. Principalmente por está funcionando até mesmo no IE7. Realmente incrível. Uma coisa que eu estava tentando fazer no antigo plugin, era capturar o nome da ID do dropdown, e transforma-la em uma classe, e adiciona-la no botão, no container do dropdown e também no body. assim: `js-button-dropdown2` `js-content-dropdown2` `js-body-dropdown2` saca.

Comment: era ruim mesmo, agora que estou percebendo isso. Agora, e se eu quiser manter a solução da pergunta, em apenas um desse dropdowns? Por exemplo. Terei três dropdowns, numa página. Mas apenas um deles deve ficar desse jeito ai. Os outros podem ser normais. Fechando clicando fora.

Comment: Uma última coisa, e ficará redondinho. Dentro desse menu **fechafora** gostária de evitar o fechamento dele com o right-click ativo dentro dele.

Comment: testei, não está passando. Ele continua fechando quando tenta abrir um link em uma nova aba com o contextmenu.

Comment: Estou no FF, no GC, funciona.

Comment: veja agora........

Comment: perfeito, por hoje é só. Thx.

Comment: não sei bem porque, tenho uma sensação de que essa sua solução poderia resolver isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/302785/95735

Answer (score 2):

Seguindo a orientação do Leandro, não usei o plugin `Jquery DropDown`  <sub>**é muito ruim, a documentação é rídicula**</sub>. Usei a biblioteca **bootstrap**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.dropdown.keep-open').on({
    "shown.bs.dropdown": function() { this.closable = false; },
    "click":             function() { this.closable = true; },
    "hide.bs.dropdown":  function() { return this.closable; }
});


});
```

```css
.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown keep-open">
    <!-- Dropdown Button -->
    
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" data-jq-dropdown="#jq-dropdown-1"><span class="abrir">Abrir Dropdown</span>

    
    <!-- Dropdown Menu -->
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" 
        aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <li><a href="#">Science</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Eletronics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pellentesque convallis enim.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Internet</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```