# Reusando um código jquery para carregamentos de posts WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery

Possuo um código, que carrega posts wordpress via ajax. Funciona muito bem em todos templates. Index, tag, categorias, etc. O que me chama a atenção nesse código é que aparentemente o carregamento é feito através das divs, não sei explicar bem, só sei que apenas com esse código js é possível carregar os posts com ajax apenas clicando no botão Load More. Já fiz vários experimentos, em outros temas e vi que é bem isso mesmo. Pensei que se é com base nas classes/id dos elementos que é feito a chamada dos posts. Então acho que seria possível utilizar esse mesmo código para carregar posts de Querys personalizadas, numa mesma página. Imagine por exemplo, três caixas, que listam posts de 3 categorias diferentes.

Desse jeito aqui:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Quero reusar esse código para fazer isso ai.

PS: Eu estava pensando... eu conheço o funcionamento do `.attr` mas não sei como poderia aplica-lo em caso desses. Se o botão que carrega os posts fosse utilizado primeiro para pegar a ID dos boxes, aplica-lo ao código, e carregar os posts `(".minha-classe-ajax").attr('id')`.

Com o código abaixo, aplicado a qualquer tema wordpress, é possível ver o resultado.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
 $body  = jQuery('body');
var load_ajax_new_count = 0;
$("body").on('click', '.ajax-load-button a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $link = $(this);
    var page_url = $link.attr("href");
    $link.addClass('ajax-loader');
    $body.addClass('opt-pagination-loading');
    $('.ajax-pagination-ajax').addClass('ajax-ajaxpagination-active');
    $("<div>").load(page_url, function() {
        var n = load_ajax_new_count.toString();
        var $wrap = $link.closest('.ajax-primary-main').find('.ajax-primary-content');
        var $new = $(this).find('.ajax-primary-content .ajax-post').addClass('animated fadeInUp ajax-poajax-new-' + n);
        var $this_div = $(this);

        $new.hide().appendTo($wrap).fadeIn(400);

        if ($this_div.find('.ajax-load-button').length) {
            $link.closest('.ajax-primary-main').find('.ajax-load-button').html($this_div.find('.ajax-load-button').html());
            $body.removeClass('opt-pagination-loading');
            $('.ajax-pagination-ajax').removeClass('ajax-ajaxpagination-active');


        } else {
            $link.closest('.ajax-primary-main').find('.ajax-load-button').fadeOut('fast').remove();
        }

        if (page_url != window.location) {
            window.history.pushState({
                path: page_url
            }, '', page_url);
        }

        load_ajax_new_count++;

        return false;
    });

});

});
```

```html
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="container">

<div id="box-latest" class="box-container ajax-primary-main">
 <h1 class="box-title">BOX LATEST</h1>
    <div class="ajax-primary-content">
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
        <article class="ajax-post">
            <h1 class="post-title">
             <a itemprop="url" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
             <?php the_title();?>
             </a>
            </h1>
            <p class="post-meta">
             <span class="category"><?php the_category();?></span>
             <span class="date"><?php $post_date = get_the_date(); echo $post_date;?></span>
             <span class="author"><a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) );?>"><?php echo get_the_author();?></a></span>
            </p>
        </article>
        <?php endwhile;?>
    </div><!-- ajax-primary-content -->
    
    <div id="ajax-pagination" class="ajax-load-button">
        <div class="ajax-pagination-ajax">
            <?php echo $more_link = get_next_posts_link('<span class="pagination-load">Load More</span>'); ?>
        </div>
    </div><!-- #ajax-pagination -->
    
</div><!-- ajax-primary-main -->


</div> <!-- .container -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**EXEMPLO EM HTML DA IMAGEM.**

```css
 .main-layout {
  margin: 0px auto;
  max-width: 761px;
 }
    .main-box h2,
  .main-box h3 {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }

  .box-title {
   padding: 10px;
   margin-left: -10px;
   color: #fff
  }

  #main-box-1 .box-title h3 {
   background:#325
  }
  #main-box-2 .box-title h3 {
   background: #000
  }
  #main-box-3 .box-title h3 {
   background: #333
  }

  .box-title h3 {
   padding: 10px;
  }
  .main-box-title {
   font-size: 16px;
  }
  .main-box-title a {
   text-decoration: none;
  }
  .main-box-title a:hover {
   color: #333
  }
  .main-box {
   max-width: 761px;
   margin: 0px auto;
   margin-bottom: 30px;
  }

  .main-box-loop {
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   vertical-align: top;
   zoom:-1px;
   margin: 0;
   max-width: 32.5%;
  }
  .main-load-more {
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
  }
  .main-load-more a {
   margin: 10px auto;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 10px;
   display: inline-block;
   background: #ddd;
   text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
 <div class="main-layout">

 <div id="main-box-1" class="main-box">

  <div class="box-title">
   <h3>Esportes</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="main-box-container">

   <div class="main-box-loop">
    <div class="main-box-image">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150">
    </div><!-- .main-box-image -->
    <h2 class="main-box-title">
     <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</a>
    </h2>
   </div> <!-- .main-box-loop -->

   <div class="main-box-loop">
    <div class="main-box-image">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150">
    </div><!-- .main-box-image -->
    <h2 class="main-box-title">
     <a href="#">Vivamus at eleifend leo. Praesent eu ex ligula. </a>
    </h2>
   </div> <!-- .main-box-loop -->

   <div class="main-box-loop">
    <div class="main-box-image">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150">
    </div><!-- .main-box-image -->
    <h2 class="main-box-title">
     <a href="#">Aenean hendrerit pretium odio, nec pretium nisl ornare vitae.</a>
    </h2>
   </div> <!-- .main-box-loop -->

   <div class="main-load-more">
    <a href="#">Load More</a>
   </div>

  </div> <!-- .main-box-container -->

 </div> <!-- #main-box-1 -->


 <div id="main-box-2" class="main-box">

  <div class="box-title">
   <h3>Science</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="main-box-container">

   <div class="main-box-loop">
    <div class="main-box-image">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150">
    </div><!-- .main-box-image -->
    <h2 class="main-box-title">
     <a href="#">Sed tristique tempor arcu sit amet facilisis.</a>
    </h2>
   </div> <!-- .main-box-loop -->

   <div class="main-box-loop">
    <div class="main-box-image">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150">
    </div><!-- .main-box-image -->
    <h2 class="main-box-title">
     <a href="#">Cras accumsan condimentum urna id tincidunt.</a>
    </h2>
   </div> <!-- .main-box-loop -->

   <div class="main-box-loop">
    <div class="main-box-image">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150">
    </div><!-- .main-box-image -->
    <h2 class="main-box-title">
     <a href="#">Sed sem eros, cursus in dapibus a, viverra id lorem.</a>
    </h2>
   </div> <!-- .main-box-loop -->

   <div class="main-load-more">
    <a href="#">Load More</a>
   </div>

  </div> <!-- .main-box-container -->

 </div> <!-- #main-box-2 -->

 <div id="main-box-3" class="main-box">

  <div class="box-title">
   <h3>Tec</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="main-box-container">

   <div class="main-box-loop">
    <div class="main-box-image">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150">
    </div><!-- .main-box-image -->
    <h2 class="main-box-title">
     <a href="#">Aenean eget justo eu turpis auctor gravida. </a>
    </h2>
   </div> <!-- .main-box-loop -->

   <div class="main-box-loop">
    <div class="main-box-image">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150">
    </div><!-- .main-box-image -->
    <h2 class="main-box-title">
     <a href="#">Mauris in metus vitae libero laoreet malesuada vel a turpis.</a>
    </h2>
   </div> <!-- .main-box-loop -->

   <div class="main-box-loop">
    <div class="main-box-image">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150">
    </div><!-- .main-box-image -->
    <h2 class="main-box-title">
     <a href="#">Sed tincidunt, arcu quis commodo auctor, purus erat egestas metus, luctus tempor orci quam sed augue. </a>
    </h2>
   </div> <!-- .main-box-loop -->

   <div class="main-load-more">
    <a href="#">Load More</a>
   </div>

  </div> <!-- .main-box-container -->

 </div> <!-- #main-box-3 -->


</div> <!-- .main-layout -->
```

Comment: O código que você postou está incompleto. Esse JS apenas conta quantos posts foram carregados. Não tem chamada AJAX ali. Hoje a melhor forma de fazer essa chamada é utilizando a REST API. Você busca os posts em json e insere o conteúdo no HTML. Coloca o HTML daquela imagem lá de cima aqui que eu faço um exemplo pra vc...

Comment: @RicardoBRGWeb fiz como pediu, adicionei o html da imagem acima. Tá na pergunta e também no codepen. https://codepen.io/johnquimera/pen/yEaNjL